# With foreach parallel, when I run for more than 100 loops the list structure fails

Tags: r, list, parallel-processing

I want to parallelise the processing of 250 files, when I attempt to process more than 100, the list structure fails.

If I run this code with `exponent = 1:100` it works but if I run it with `exponent = 1:101` it fails with a message

```
Warning message:
Element 2 has length 2 not 100
```

Any exponent loop less than 101 is OK but any loop over 100 fails with multiple warning messages. Here is the code:

```
library(doParallel)

remove(list=ls())

cl <- makeCluster(5)
registerDoParallel(cl)

exp.list<-
  foreach(exponent = 1:100, .combine = list,
      .multicombine = TRUE)  %dopar%  {
        x1<-runif(1000,0,10)
        x2<-runif(1000,10,100)
        x.df<-data.frame(x1,x2)
        y1<-runif(10,100,110)
        y2<-runif(10,110,200)
        y.df<-data.frame(y1,y2)
        list(x.df,y.df)
      }
exp.list.t<-purrr::transpose(exp.list)
x<-do.call("rbind", exp.list.t[[1]])
y<-do.call("rbind", exp.list.t[[2]])

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Your example code runs without error. It's *very* likely that the actual problem is file number 101. Run the loop with `exponent = 101` and `%do%`. Is there an error? Is the expected result returned for this file?

Comment: @Roland there's no files being read in and I get the error when I run from 1:101, or 100:201. And simplifying the expression results in errors too. Its the `maxcombine` value...

Comment: According to linked answer use `.maxcombine = 101` when using `.multicombine = TRUE`

Comment: Thanks Spacedman and PoGibas, your suggestion works. Notes : (1) I did not use exactly the code I have since it would be complicated with 100+ files, instead I re-created the same issue without the need for external files. (2) The issued looked to be with `foreach` and not `purrr`. I will post the solution code.